# Sunspot:: How do you return joined results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

I have a many to many table and I want to return the results in my search return. How do i do this?

```
model User
  has_many :jobs, :through => user_jobs

  searchable do 
   text :name, :sort_name
   integer :id
   integer :, :multiple => true, :references => Job
  end
end

model UserJob
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :jobs
end

model Job
  has_many :users, :through => user_jobs
end
```